# Is it possible to create webservices with JAX-RS at runtime?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Given the following class that has no dependency on the JAX-RS library:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public String getMessage() {

        return "Hello world!"

    }

}
```

Would it be possible to create a webservice from the above class, at runtime, so that it responds as if it were this?

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    public String getMessage() {

        return Response.ok("Hello world!").build();

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "at runtime"? How is it running the first class?

Comment: What you can have is have a "Generic" service class that, takes a path parameter and the invokeService of that class can delegate to HelloWorld.getMessage... if path parameter hello is called.

Comment: Are you saying you have a known class whose functionality needs to be returned by a REST service, or are you saying you don’t know until runtime which class/method’s functionality will be returned by the REST service?

Comment: Hi @Hector. I mean I have an application running on a JEE server and this application will need to dynamically create webservices from information obtained at runtime. I would like to know if it is possible in JAXRS to determine the paths and classes / Methods that answer these services without having to stop the server.

Comment: Hi @Optional. Your suggestion works, but in this case I would be using QueryParam to determine services paths. I'd like to know if it's possible to dynamically create services and their paths while an application is running.

Comment: Hi @VGR. I don’t know until runtime which class/method’s functionality will be returned by the REST service.

Comment: @marcelo-mota-ribeiro instead of path params, you can use query Param but design can remain same

Comment: Is there a known, limited set of methods that your application might want to run?  If so, you should follow @Optional’s suggestion.  Use the QueryParam parameter to look up a method reference in a Map.

Comment: @VGR This suggestion is considered, if an initial idea is not possible. Thank you.